# Sort array based on data

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, xml-parsing, nsarray

I have a tableview that displays data from an array stored in a NSObject. One of the properties in the NSObject is inputtime (currentCall.inputtime) and I want to sort my displayed data based on that. How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    JointCAD *currentCall = [[xmlParser calls] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString *cellidentifier1 = @"cell1";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier1];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier1];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = currentCall.currentCallType;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = currentCall.location;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you should do is instead of sorting the cells in cellForRow, you should be sorting your array ahead of time and then calling `[tableview reloadData]`.

There are many ways to sort your array, and without knowing all of the information about your object one way to sort by date is as follows.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"inputtime" ascending:TRUE];
[myMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort your data modell first. But outside of the method `didSelectRowforIndexPath`.

Some where in your code you access:

```
currentCall = [[xmlParser calls] objectAtIndex
```

At this time the array must already be sorted.

Do that sorting e.g in `ViewWillAppear`. 
In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the data already must be sorted.

If the data modell changes dynamically, e.g. by deleting of cell rows, then you have to relod your  table data with  `[self.tableView reloadData]`

Comment: The data is parsed before in an array? All I want to do is sort the xmlParser.calls array based on currentCall.inputtime

Comment: All [xmlParser calls] is, is an array, its not doing parsing or anything if that's what your thinking its doing.